# deleting files with python scripts

Tags: python, file

I want to delete some files with python scripts (while using Windows). I have tried the following code:

```
>>>import os
>>> os.remove ('D:\new.docx')
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in -toplevel-

    os.remove ('D:\new.docx')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\new.docx'
```

Can anyone here help me with this?

THanks.

Gillani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options:

Escape the `backslash`:

```
>>> os.remove('D:\\new.docx')
```

The runtime library in Windows accepts a `forward slash` as a separator:

```
>>> os.remove('D:/new.docx')
```

[Raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
>>> os.remove(r'D:\new.docx')
```

Answer (score 6):

`\` is the escape char for python. try replacing it with `\\` .

ex:

```
os.remove ('D:\\new.docx')
```